# FPS drops/freezes/"stutter" on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, gpu, fps

So, my son has a decent gaming machine. AND Ryzen 5600X CPU on an ASUS TUF GAMING B550M-PLUS motherboard, 32G RAM, 512 G SSD, the graphics card is a GIGABYTE GeForce RTX3060Ti.

The FPS in the games he plays, from CS2 to Fortnite, is rather good most of the time, but he has occasional sudden drops to half or more or else momentary screen freezes, then the performance comes back. Moreover he noticed mouse cursor stuttering on the normal Windows screen. And testufo is reporting "browser stutter". Looking at the Task Manager and at MSI Afterburner stat monitoring does not seem to show any cause. In particular the CPU and GPU temperatures look perfectly fine.

I have searched this website but the only suggestion I found was about "locking the GPU frequency" in MSI Afterburner. After some experimentation he found a way to make the voltage/frequency curve flat. Making it flat at 1700 caused immediate screen corruption/ Making it flat at 1300 lowered overall FPS and did not resolve the FPS falls and freezes.

So - what should we do to fix and/or diagnose the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. See if other tasks are running. 2. Try free Intelligent Standby List Cleaner, https://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1256/, which speeds up Windows reuse of RAM. Might or might not help, but it's a quick test to try. If it works, report back and make it an answer.